BitLocker requires Key after aborting UBUNTU installation
I am trying to install Ubuntu on a friend's new laptop, alongside with the pre-installed Windows.  As BitLocker was active on Windows, we aborted the installation routine in order to go back to Windows and deactivate BitLocker.  But we cannot go back to Windows, as BitLocker complains that something has already been changed and that we need to insert the BitLocker Key in order to regain access to the Windows partition.  We have no clue where to find the BL. Key, as we did not use a Microsoft account for anything so far, and it did not come on paper or elsewhere when we bought the laptop.
Why does the UBUNTU installation touch the BitLocker settings even before installing anything?
And more importantly, what can we do now?  We need both operational systems, Windows and UBUNTU, for different tasks.  I would be very upset if I would need to buy a new version of Windows and re-install it from scratch just because I wanted to install UBUNTU alongside with the pre-installed OS.
Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

I don't use BitLocker on PC which dual boots Ubuntu and Windows to test it, but do the answers in BitLocker asking for protection code after Ubuntu installation help?

To dualboot with Windows with Bitlocker enabled, you first need to disable Bitlocker. How to find the Bitlocker recovery key has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You may check out Windows help page on how to find your Bitlocker recovery key.

You never need to buy a new Windows, The ISO to reinstall is free. The activation key is embedded on the machine. Reinstall on a new machine may be the easiest way, then turn off bitlocker before the Ubuntu installation.

We can really only be generic in details anyway; you mention Ubuntu, but gave no specifics as to what Ubuntu product & release of that product, so we don't know what installer you used anyway (there are currently four installers selected by ISO downloaded & used). You can proceed a long way into the install process & then back out without any consequence; but you gave no clear detail as to how far you got on your unspecified installer & if writes had actually started.   Ubuntu installers don't touch the system until user accepts/approves changes & thus modifications are mandatory.
